# A Pythonic approach to a list comparison/generation script

Tags: python-3.x

Consider I've got a list of 2-tuples named `listuple` and another simple list named `list0`. I want to generate a list of `1`s and `-1`s based on comparing my two given lists.

```
def Vectomparison (listuple, list0):
    result = []
    for EachElement in listuple:
        if EachElement [0] in list0:
            result.append (1)
        else:
            result.append (-1)
    return result
```

But I really think that this not a Pythonic approach. Any idea for making this ***Pythonically*** more compressed?

Answer (score 2):

A direct rewrite using a list comprehesion, and ternary operator:

```
def Vectomparison (listuple, list0):
  return [1 if item[0] in list0 else -1 for item in listuple]
```

Note that `item[0] in list0` uses a linear search if `list0` is a list. That makes the algorithms time complexity `O(N*M)` where `N = len(listuple), M = len(list0)`

You can make it faster:

```
def Vectomparison (listuple, list0):
  set0 = set(list0)
  return [1 if item[0] in set0 else -1 for item in listuple]
```

This version has a time complexity of `O(N+M)`

Comment: Please, how do you estimate/formulate time complexity in such problems?

Comment: A linear search on a list takes `O(N)` steps. Doing it `M` times yields in a `O(N*M)` algorithm. In the second example building the set takes `O(M)` time (as inserting a new element is `O(1)`), and building the final list is `O(N)`, so overall `O(N+M)`

Comment: @MerlotLatterian also i suggest you to use lowercase function names